# Rails associations  (many-to-many nightmare)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, associations

I have an organisation that has many products.  These products are in various categories.  There is also more than one organisation.  And a product can be in more than one category.

How would I setup my models and associations so that I could do the following :

```
@org = Organisation.first

@org.categories  => spits out a list of categories being used by the products for that organisation
@org.products => spits out a list of products for that organisation
@org.categories[0].products => spits out a list of products for the first category
```

Also, I'd like the categories to be available to other organisations so that if I happen to create a category when adding a product in organisation 1, then that category will also be available for product I'm adding for organisation 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably how you should set up your models ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)):

**EDIT: Updated answer**

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def categories
    # I don't like this way anymore
    # @_categories ||= products.map(&:categories).flatten.uniq
    # Do this
    @categories ||= Category.for_organisation(self)
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories  # foreign keys in the join table
  # A product references an organisation.
  belongs_to :organisation             # foreign key - organisation_id
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products    # foreign keys in the join table

  def self.for_organisation(org)
    query = %{
      id in (
        select category_id from categories_products where product_id in (
          select id from products where organisation_id = ? ) )
    }
    where(query, org.id)
  end
end
```

Possible gotcha: this requires a join table that has no corresponding model or primary key

Here is an [example app](https://github.com/invisiblefunnel/soquestion) using this technique. The readme will get you started.

Comment: I created a spec https://gist.github.com/980044 to test this and most of it is working!  Thank you!
However on line 20 it fails with the error :Invalid source reflection macro :has_and_belongs_to_many for has_many :categories, :through => :products.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.

Comment: I thought things might get a little wonky because it's going `:through` a HABTM. Might have to explicitly declare the `has_many`'s and `:belongs_to`'s between categories and products. I'll edit my answer. Might try `has_many :categories, :through => :products, :source => :product` but it seems unlikely to work.

Comment: @RobZolkos I think `:source` might need to be the name of the join table.

Comment: I think the best solution might be a custom categories accessor method on the organisation model. I have build an example rails app with an expanded test suite. The README will get you started, let me know what you think about this solution. Good luck. https://github.com/invisiblefunnel/soquestion

Comment: Thank you so much :)  That works perfectly.  Thank you for putting the time in to answering this one.  Cheers